# A proof about boundedness for continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I := [a,b]$ and let $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(x) > 0$ for each $x$ in $I$. Prove that there exists a number $a > 0$ such that $f(x) \geq a$ for all $x$ in $I$.

Here is what I did:

By max-min theorem, there exists an $a = \inf f(I)$.

Since $f$ is continuous and bounded on $I$ (by boundedness theorem), there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ bounded on $I$ that converges to $x_*$ (also in $I$), where $f(x_*) = a$.

Therefore, $f(x_*) > 0$ and then $a > 0$.

I feel like I am missing something, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: The interval $[a,b]$ is closed, so the function attains a minimum $m$ in this interval. But $f(x)\gt 0$ in the interval, so $m\gt 0$. (One should not use $a$ both for the left endpoint of the interval and the minimum value.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x)$ where $x\in(0,\infty)$.

Now take the global minimum of $f(x)$ on the whole real line. Call this value  $m$. Now if I take take any $a$ such that $a<m$, the condition holds true.